# ASP.NET Core - Error handling send email and present error page

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have the following code in my `startup.cs` to email any errors in the application:

```
app.UseExceptionHandler(
    options =>
    {
        //options.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        options.Run(
            async context =>
            {
                var ex = context.Features.Get<IExceptionHandlerFeature>();
                if (ex != null)
                {
                    var err = $"<h1>Error: {ex.Error.Message}</h1>{ex.Error.Source}<hr />{context.Request.Path}<br />";
                    err += $"QueryString: {context.Request.QueryString}<hr />";

                    err += $"Stack Trace<hr />{ex.Error.StackTrace.Replace(Environment.NewLine, "<br />")}";
                    if (ex.Error.InnerException != null)
                        err +=
                            $"Inner Exception<hr />{ex.Error.InnerException?.Message.Replace(Environment.NewLine, "<br />")}";

                    if (context.Request.Form.Any())
                    {
                        err += "<table border=\"1\"><tr><td colspan=\"2\">Form collection:</td></tr>";
                        foreach (var form in context.Request.Form)
                        {
                            err += $"<tr><td>{form.Key}</td><td>{form.Value}</td></tr>";
                        }
                        err += "</table>";
                    }

                    await msg.SendEmailAsync(appSettings.Value.ErrorDeliveryEmailAddress, "CMP v2 error",
                        err);
                    context.Response.Redirect("/Home/Error?r=" +
                                                System.Net.WebUtility.UrlEncode(context.Request.Path + "?" +
                                                                                context.Request.QueryString));
                }
            });
        //options.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
        //options.UseStatusCodePagesWithReExecute("/Home/Error/{0}");
    }
);
```

However, it does pick up 404 errors.

How can I use the:

```
app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
app.UseStatusCodePagesWithReExecute("/Home/Error/{0}");
```

Code, and still email the error details to a support queue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was very close, the error handling was failing when hitting an error without a form collection - such as a 404 etc...

So:

```
app.UseExceptionHandler(
    options =>
    {
        //options.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        options.Run(
            async context =>
            {
                var ex = context.Features.Get<IExceptionHandlerFeature>();
                if (ex != null)
                {
                    var err = $"<h1>Error: {ex.Error.Message}</h1>{ex.Error.Source}<hr />{context.Request.Path}<br />";
                    err += $"QueryString: {context.Request.QueryString}<hr />";

                    err += $"Stack Trace<hr />{ex.Error.StackTrace.Replace(Environment.NewLine, "<br />")}";
                    if (ex.Error.InnerException != null)
                        err +=
                            $"Inner Exception<hr />{ex.Error.InnerException?.Message.Replace(Environment.NewLine, "<br />")}";
                    // This bit here to check for a form collection!
                    if (context.Request.HasFormContentType && context.Request.Form.Any())
                    {
                        err += "<table border=\"1\"><tr><td colspan=\"2\">Form collection:</td></tr>";
                        foreach (var form in context.Request.Form)
                        {
                            err += $"<tr><td>{form.Key}</td><td>{form.Value}</td></tr>";
                        }
                        err += "</table>";
                    }

                    await msg.SendEmailAsync(appSettings.Value.ErrorDeliveryEmailAddress, "CMP v2 error",
                        err);
                    context.Response.Redirect("/Home/Error?r=" +
                                                System.Net.WebUtility.UrlEncode(context.Request.Path + "?" +
                                                                                context.Request.QueryString));
                }
            });
        //options.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
        options.UseStatusCodePagesWithReExecute("/Home/Error/{0}");
    }
);
```

The key check being `context.Request.HasFormContentType && context.Request.Form.Any()`

Answer (score 1):

If you add this to your Configure method in Startup.cs, then you can catch and handle 404 errors:

```
  app.Use(async (context, next) =>
  {
    await next();
    if (context.Response.StatusCode == 404)
    {
      //handle the 404 response here
    }
  });
```

Comment: Is there a way to use `app.UseStatusCodePagesWithReExecute("/Home/Error/{0}");` - would that just go under `await next()`?

Answer (score 1):

You could implement the logger using these methods:

```
  public void Log<TState>(LogLevel logLevel, EventId eventId, TState state, Exception exception, Func<TState, Exception, string> formatter)
    {

        if (exception != null)
        {
            // Add the details of the Http Request if present
            var stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
            var httpContext = _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext;
            if (httpContext != null)
            {
                var request = httpContext.Request;
                stringBuilder.Append("User: ").Append(_userManager.GetUserName(httpContext.User)).Append("<br/>")
                    .Append("Address: ").Append($"{request.Scheme}://{request.Host}{request.Path}{request.QueryString}").Append("<br/>")
                    .Append("Local IP address: ").Append(httpContext.Connection.LocalIpAddress).Append("<br/>")
                    .Append("Remote IP address: ").Append(httpContext.Connection.RemoteIpAddress).Append("<br/>");
            }
            EmailException(exception, stringBuilder);
        }
    }

    private void EmailException(Exception exception, StringBuilder stringBuilder)
    {
        BuildExceptionText(stringBuilder, "<h1>Error </h1>", exception);

        _emailSender.SendMailAsync(
            _smtpDetails.Value, new List<string> { _configuration["ErrorDeliveryEmailAddress"] },
            "System Error", stringBuilder.ToString()).ConfigureAwait(false);
    }

    private StringBuilder BuildExceptionText(StringBuilder stringBuilder, string title, Exception exception)
    {
        stringBuilder.Append(title).Append("<h2>").Append(exception.Message).Append("</h2><br/>")
           .Append(exception.Source ?? "").Append("<hr/>");
        if (exception.StackTrace != null)
        {
            stringBuilder.Append("<h3>Stack trace: </h3><br/>").Append(exception.StackTrace.Replace(Environment.NewLine, "<br/>"));
        }

        if (exception.InnerException != null)
        {
            BuildExceptionText(stringBuilder, "<h2>Inner exception </h2>", exception.InnerException);
        }

        return stringBuilder;
    }
```

I have written about this here: https://jdono.com/2018/05/01/asp-net-core-2-0-c-sending-errors-by-email-using-ilogger/

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/19601104)

Comment: @RenanAraújo I have updated the post with the relevant code from the blog.

Comment: I'd also suggest capturing any form submission items as part of the http context, as this is useful debugging information as well.